# How do I update/set/unset a key in embedded document/array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to unset all values in a document that's embedded in an array. Let's say I have a collection `coll` with array `things`, containing a value `myval`. I want to unset `myval`.  This looks like:

```
{ things: [{ myval: 1 }, { myval: 2 }] }
```

I've tried both

```
db.coll.update({}, {$unset: {'things.myval': 1}})
```

and

```
db.coll.things.update({}, {$unset: {'myval': 1}})
```

Neither of these work. I can't find any documentation online describing how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this and was frustrated to see the only was to do this was using a nested forEach. So after some searching I found another way! Since mongo version 3.6 there is a [all positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) (`$[]`) (version 3.6 was introduced way after this question was asked... and even after it was last active, BUT incase anyone else comes across this)

To remove the column `myval` from the first embedded document to match, do this:

```
db.coll.update(
  {things: {'$exists': true}},
  {$unset: {'things.$[].myval': 1}}
)
```

or if you want to remove it from all document that match use the `updateMany`

```
db.coll.updateMany(
  {things: {'$exists': true}},
  {$unset: {'things.$[].myval': 1}}
)
```

The `$unset` will only edit it if the value exists but it will not do a safe navigation (i.e. it wont check it things exists first) so the exists is needed on the embedded document/array.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a value from an "array" using the *$pull* operator:

```
db.coll.update({}, {$pull: {'things': {'myval': 1}}});
```

Also have a look at the documentation of *$pull*:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull

Answer (score 1):

Should work with your first approach according with the official documentation:

```
db.coll.update({}, {$unset: {'things.myval': 1}})
```

But that doesn't work for me to. So, the solution I found, applied to your example was:

```
db.coll.find().forEach(function(o) {
    for(var i=0; i<o.things.length; i++) {
        var unset = {};
        unset["things." + i + ".myval"] = "";
        db.coll.update( { "_id": o._id  }, { "$unset": unset } );
    }
})
```

Or with a more functional style:

```
db.coll.find().forEach(function(o) {
    o.things.forEach(function(t, i) {
        var unset = {};
        unset["things." + i + ".myval"] = "";
        db.coll.update( { "_id": o._id  }, { "$unset": unset } );
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

It can't work because the {}-empty selector selects more than one documents, and update normally try to update a single document.In order to make it work, use the [multi](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29) flag to tell mongo update that more than one document is comin.

> multi - indicates if all documents matching criteria should be updated
>   rather than just one. Can be useful with the $ operators below.

```
db.coll.update({}, {$unset: {'things.myval': 1}},false,true)
```

or

```
db.coll.update({}, {$pull: {'things': {'myval': 1}}},false,true)
```

Try either one and will see which one works, but you have to use multi param in both

Comment: $unset will not work on objects in arrays, and $pull removes the entire object, and thus is not semantically equivalent...